# FFMPEG - Hardcoding (burning) filename in video

Tags: ffmpeg

I was wondering if someone can help me adding a hardcoded filename using the drawtext filter in FFMPEG?

I can easily add timecode now, but I want to also add the filename of the current file. Is that possible?

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "P1010377.MOV" -c:a libfaac -q:a 150 -c:v libx264 -crf:v 12 -preset:v veryslow -intra -filter:v "scale=640:-1,drawtext=fontsize=15:fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=25:fontsize=32:fontcolor='white':box=1:boxcolor=0x000000AA:x=10:y=10" "P1010377.MOV.MP4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extra drawfilters to the chain by comma separating them

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "P1010377.MOV" -c:a libfaac -q:a 150 -c:v libx264 -crf:v 12 -preset:v veryslow -intra -vf "scale=640:-1, drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf:text='some filename.mp4':x=100:y=100:fontcolor='white', drawtext=fontsize=15:fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=25:fontsize=32:fontcolor='white':box=1:boxcolor=0x000000AA:x=10:y=10" "P1010377.MOV.MP4"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to have FFMPEG self-reference to the file it's processing - without passing it as an argument to the command-line. Is that possible?

Comment: if it happens to be in the videos metadata you might be able to get it with `text=%{metadata\:filename}` (or similar) but passing in the known filename argument is more likely to work. https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-drawtext-1

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but had to do something similar, so i'll share it here.

It's based on 'user3770489's first answer, adding a automatic filename insertion, but still using shell expansion/argument to the command line.

Assuming you'r not in a for/while loop over a set of movie files, but processing a single file, you could:

```
fn="P1010377.MOV" && /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$fn" -c:a libfaac -q:a 150 -c:v libx264 \ 
  -crf:v 12 -preset:v veryslow -intra -filter:v \ 
    "scale=640:-1,drawtext=fontsize=15:fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf: \ 
    text='File=[$fn] - TC=': timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': rate=25:fontsize=32: \ 
    fontcolor='white':box=1:boxcolor=0x000000AA:x=10:y=10" \ 
  ${fn/.MOV/.MOV.MP4}
```